# Extract data for all groups in a single SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, order-by

MySQL 5.

```
Table: schedule
Columns:
id  int(10) UN PK AI
startdate   date 
groupid smallint(5) UN
```

The following statement extracts the Schedule ID for a given group (the schedule with the latest date not greater than the given date):

```
SELECT id FROM schedule
WHERE groupid=@group AND @date>=startdate
ORDER BY startdate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Question: Can I extract Schedule IDs for all groups, without enumerating (calling the above statement repeatedly) with all existing group IDs?

Comment: Does `(groupid)` have a unique constraint? Or that `UN` means unsigned?

Comment: @ypercube: that UN means unsigned. There is a unique index for the pair `groupid`, `startdate`. There are no other unique constraints (not counting the primary key for ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, provided the combination `groupid - startdate` is unique:

```
SELECT s1.groupid, s1.id FROM schedule s1, (
  SELECT groupid, MAX(startdate) startdate
  FROM schedule
  WHERE @date >= startdate
  GROUP BY groupid
) s2
WHERE s1.groupid = s2.groupid
AND s1.startdate = s2.startdate
```